# Query Filter Results

Tags: google-sheets, google-query-language

I am trying to query and then filter my results based on the drop down in N4

```
=
IF(and(N4="ALL"), query(Vendors!1:1000,"select A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H, I, J, K, L", 2),

IF(and(N4="Trained"), query(Vendors!1:1000,"select A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H, I, J, K, L", 2),
IF(and(N4="Requested"), query(Vendors!1:1000,"select A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H, I, J, K, L", 2),
IF(and(N4="Invited"), query(Vendors!1:1000,"select A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H, I, J, K, L", 2)))))
```

Those all return results. However, now I need help omitting the results that dont match the dropdown.

Comment: In what column of Vendors do you want to match the value in N4?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry I didn't read it correctly. Try this.

```
=IF (N4 <>"ALL",IF(OR(OR( N4="Trained",N4="Requested",N4="Invited")),query(Vendors!1:1000,"select A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H, I, J, K, L where A = '"& N4 &"'")),query(Vendors!2:1000,"select A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H, I, J, K, L where A<>''"))
```

Key in the Header row. Change Column A to whatever column "Trained", "Invited", etc are in.

Comment: It querys the results but what I am trying to do is this -
If N4 dropdown = Trained then display only trained
If N4 dropdown = Requested then display only Requested
If N4 dropdown = All, display all

Comment: Check the changed answer.